# find and replace shell using file as input for search and for replace

Tags: linux, bash, shell, replace, find

I need to replace several chunks of text inside some php scripts...

i have:

```
find . -name 'products.php' -exec grep --silent 'TEXT_TO_FIND' {} \; -exec ls {} \; -exec sed -i 's/TEXT_TO_FIND/REPLACE_TEXT/g' {} \;
```

this work, but i have text of about 2 ou 3 lines..

so i remember to create a find.txt with my find text and another replace.txt with the replacement text..

my question is..
how can i use this files as inputs in the above command..

something like:

```
find . -name 'products.php' -exec grep --silent `cat find.txt` ...
```

Best regards
Bruno

Comment: Is "using Bash" a real requirement?

Comment: no, not required, but since all files are in a server which is in production i supose its the better way, right?
any sugestion?

Comment: @BrunoBraga Can you reword your question a bit. At the moment, it's completely unclear what you're asking. e.g. Why does your first command not work? `but i have text of about 2 ou 3 lines..` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to go to something more data oriented than pure-bash/coreutils. If you have access to Python on your site:

```
#!/bin/python
with open("find.txt","r") as f:
    fs = f.read().trim("r")

with open("replace.txt","r") as f:
    rs = f.read().trim()


# you probably have to loop other the following lines
# Once for every file:
with open("src.txt","r") as f:
    src = f.read()

modified = src.replace(fs,rs)
if modified := src:
    with open("src.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(modified)
```

This is only a *starting point*. You will probably have to improve it. Feel free to ask an other question if you're stuck on something!

---

Here is a transcript of my tests:

```
sh$ cat src.txt 
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
sh$ cat find.txt 
CCC
DDD
EEE
sh$ cat replace.txt 
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
sh$ python m.py
sh$ cat src.txt 
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
FFF
```